# couting values of a string in a cell and return 'paired' or not 'paired'

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, split, nested-if

hello i need some help to count characters within a string, if there is any repeated number, return "paired" or something. if anyone can help I would appreciate it, follow the example

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F5:F="",,
 IF((MID(F5:F, 4, 1)=MID(F5:F, 1, 1))+
    (MID(F5:F, 4, 1)=MID(F5:F, 7, 1)), 
 "1 - paired", "2 - not paired")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(3=QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A2)&"×"&SPLIT(A1:A2; "♦♣♠"))); "×"); 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"); "not paired"; "paired"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(3=QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(FILTER(ROW(A5:A), A5:A<>"")&"×"&
 SPLIT(FILTER(A5:A, A5:A<>""), "♦♣♠"))), "×"), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"), 
 "not paired", "paired"))
```

[image]

Comment: ty for it, but don't work to me, this is my code

=INDEX(IF(3=QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(ROW(A5:A)&"×"&SPLIT(A5:A, "♦♣♠"))), "×"), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"), "not paired", "paired"))

Comment: also my solve with MID func is 

=IF(OR(MID(F5,4,1) = MID(F5,1,1), MID(F5,4,1)=MID(F5,7,1)),"paired", "not paired")

But I really need to put it on a arrayformula idk how haha if u can help <3

Comment: @Collaxd can you share a copy / sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10mkrxCLGkOcKrm481jnsMdQTlf_kgoXUF3eWLKJnKS0/edit?usp=sharing 

@player0

Comment: @Collaxd answer and your sheet updated